# Problems running .NET Core 3.1 and SQL Server 2017 Linux images on Linux host

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core-webapi, sql-server-2017, ef-core-3.1

I'm running a Web API using .NET Core 3.1 with EF Core 3.1 connecting to a SQL Server 2017 database. Every component is built in a Linux Docker image and I'm using docker-compose with Nginx as a reverse proxy to route to my Web API.

When I test my deployment on Windows 10 using Docker Desktop, everything works perfectly. When I test the exact same images, with the exact same docker-compose.yml file on a Linux host (Ubuntu 18.04), the connection from the API to the Databse seems to drop from time to time, randomly, which is a problem when it happens in the middle of a DB write operation. I either get a 504 (timeout), or worse, a lock on a database row which blocks access to that table.

Again, if I deploy in Windows, this never happens. Only happens when the Docker host is Linux.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to find some solution for the past 3 days, but nothing I've tried corrected that behaviour on my Linux box.

One more thing. On Windows, instead of connecting the API to the DB by name (the container's name), I'm using `host.docker.internal` in the connection string. There is no equivalent for Linux. I've read about a couple of hacks, but none seem to solve my problem.

Comment: How do you know the connections are dropping. Is it possible to do Wireshark TCP trace, and see if the connections are being closed?

Comment: I'm using SSMS tools (SQL Server Profiler and the Activity Monitor), where I can see a batch being started and never completed.

Comment: Perhaps see if there is some deadlock in the database, and if that does not help start playing with the dotnet tools: dotnet trace and dotnet dump.

Comment: No deadlocks and no peformance issues. I'm using visual studio performance monitors. As I said, this never happens when deploying the exact same images using the same docker-compose file on a Windows box running Docker Desktop. Only happens when I deploy to a Linux box. Obviously, the solution is not to use a Linux box. I'm still curious as to why this happens. Also wondering why I haven't read anything on that issue.